# In Azure Devops query get multiple levels returned

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Microsoft Azure Devops

I am trying to get all the levels to show up underneath each other.

A picture might be easier.

In the below the Epic 'Mobile' has the top feature "As a driver, I want....'

Then under those ther have product backlog items.

How can I get the backlog items to show up directly under the Feature, instead of being duplicated further down?

[image: image of screen]

Here is the query I am using:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal behavior for a query with direct links. You may try to use a tree query with the parameters below:
[image]